# Use Select-String to find desired string in a string

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find all the strings I define in -Pattern in order.
For example,

```
$string = "My car is Yellow but my car seat is White. I ate Yellow Banana, Yellow lemon and White peach."

Select-String -inputObject $string -Pattern 'Yellow', 'White'

I want the result to be like this in an array object in the order it finds in the string:
Yellow
White
Yellow
Yellow
White
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-AllMatches` parameter, however it doesn't look like it will utilize both patterns in this case. Adjusting the pattern might help.

```
($string | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern 'Yellow|White').Matches.Value
```

Comment: Excellent point. The surprising discrepancy between combining `-AllMatches` with  _multiple_ patterns passed to `-Pattern` vs. a _single_ pattern that combines multiple patterns with alternation (`|`) is discussed in [GitHub issue #7765](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7765).

Answer (score 1):

You can see the matches property in list view, instead of the default custom view.  You also need -allmatches.  Oh, it didn't come up with white.

```
$string | Select-String -Pattern Yellow, White -AllMatches | format-list

IgnoreCase : True
LineNumber : 1
Line       : My car is Yellow but my car seat is White. I ate Yellow Banana, Yellow lemon and White peach.
Filename   : InputStream
Path       : InputStream
Pattern    : Yellow
Context    :
Matches    : {0, 0, 0}


Select-String -inputobject $string -Pattern Yellow, White -AllMatches | 
  % matches

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 10
Length   : 6
Value    : Yellow

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 49
Length   : 6
Value    : Yellow

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 64
Length   : 6
Value    : Yellow
```